# What is the radius of convergence of the series $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that the series $\sum b_n$ is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent.

What is the radius of convergence of the series $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$?

**My try**:
Since the series $\sum b_n$ is conditionally convergent so $b_n\to 0\implies |b_n|\to 0$.

Since $b_n\to 0$ so $|b_n|<1$ for $n\ge m$.

If we take $|x|<1$ then $ \sum|b_n||x_n|^n<\sum|x|^n\to 0$ as $|x|<1$.

Thus $p(x)$ is convergent for $|x|<1$.

If $x=1$ then $p(1)=\sum b_n$ which is convergent.

I am unable to proceed for $|x|>1$ .Will you please give some hints to proceed here?

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum b_n x^n.$ Then $\sum b_n x^n$ converges absolutely for $|x|<R.$ If $R>1,$ this includes $x=1.$ But $\sum |b_n 1^n| = \sum |b_n| = \infty.$ Thus $R\le 1,$ and since you've shown $R\ge 1,$ we have $R=1.$